# Can't connect AWS S3 ReactApp to Heroku Node/Express API

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, heroku

I have deployed a react-app to AWS S3 and a node/express API in heroku but Iam not able to connect them together event with the **cors** config in the API or proxy in the react-app
I can't find to make this correct.

frontend package.json

```
    "name": "frontend",
    "proxy": "https://planet-api-test.herokuapp.com/",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
```

app.js

```
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('')

    useEffect(() => {
        const myFunction = async () => {
            const { data } = await axios.get('/api/users')
            setMessage(data)
        }
        myFunction()
    })
```

server.js

```
import express from 'express'
import cors from 'cors'
import userRoutes from './routes/userRoutes.js'

const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())
app.use('/api/users', userRoutes)
```

error in console
[image: error in console]

Answer (score 0):

for some reason your app tries to send the request to `http` instead of `https` try to hard-code it inside the `axios.get` see what happens

Comment: with the url hardcoded in axios works good,
as you can see it try to make the request to url of the same aws s3 bucket instead of api url in the proxy package.json

Comment: try to put this in your ```index.js``` : ```axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://planet-api-test.herokuapp.com/';``` , it sets your base url, but you have to remove the proxy first.

Comment: Well, with that config `axios.defaults.baseURL = ` work fine but, is that the correct way? is ther any improvent?

Comment: I think the easier way is just deploy both of them in the same platform, why separate them?

Comment: Its the first time iam doing this and the idea is to consume the api with 3 differents interfaces. does this make sense?

Comment: what I would suggest is separate your folders into `frontend` and `backend` and deploy all of it to one place, separating them into different places would work. but I think it's less workable unless you have a really important reason

Comment: The reason is that there are going to be diferents frontends consuming the same nodejs api